# ORA-00999: invalid view name - whats the problem?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE VIEW ["Counties above average NUMBEROFINFECTIONS"] AS 
SELECT NAME, TOTALNUMBEROFINFECTIONS  
FROM COUNTRY 
WHERE TOTALNUMBEROFINFECTIONS > (SELECT AVG(TOTALNUMBEROFINFECTIONS) FROM COUNTRY)
```

Comment: Why would you give a view a name that needs to be escaped in the first place?

Comment: What database technology?  It would determine the issue.  Without that cant say for sure, but try no spaces in view name

Comment: valid view names must begin with a letter, consist of only alphanumeric characters and the special characters $, _, and #, be **less than or equal to 30 characters**, and may not be reserved words. If the view name contains other characters, it must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

if you are in `Oracle` or `sql server` remove brackets:

```
CREATE VIEW "Counties above average NUMBEROFINFECTIONS" AS ....
```

brackets only works in `sql server` :

```
CREATE VIEW [Counties above average NUMBEROFINFECTIONS] AS  ...
```

however why you name your view that needs tobe escaped , not a good practice at all

Also `Bryan Dellinger` brought to my attention:

- In [Oracle 12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/REFRN/ALL_OBJECTS.htm#REFRN20146) and above the maximum object name length is 128 bytes.
- In [Oracle 12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) and below the maximum object name length is 30 bytes.

Comment: think the name is still too long.  CREATE VIEW "Counties above average NUMBEROFINFECTIONS" ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Comment: @BryanDellinger your fiddle is empty , however I think the length is not a problem, that works for me [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=efd8f87560cad3b98333b27d10b08e2c)

Comment: ah must have changed after 11g. if you run your fiddle as 11g you will get the error

Comment: @BryanDellinger yes ,seems like its an oracle version thing